# My Dataproc cluster (version - 1.4.0-debian9) HA mode not working

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, hadoop-yarn, high-availability, google-cloud-dataproc

I created a Dataproc cluster using image **1.4.0-debian9** with all required HA configurations, but looks like Active RM is not able to sync up with Standby RMs and hence misses information like nodelabel details, nodes running on them, etc. on failover.

Although same level of configuration works just fine with my Ambari Cluster.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Please, add full command (including all the properties that you set) that you use to create a cluster. Also, what exactly doesn't work in HA mode?

Answer (score 0):

This is an almost 1-year old image, instead of hardcoding subminor image version you should create cluster using the latest Dataproc `1.4-debian` image:

```sh
CLUSTER_NAME=<cluster_name>
REGION=<region>
gcloud dataproc clusters create $CLUSTER_NAME --image-version=1.4-debian --region=$REGION
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Igor.
Is this is a known issue for dataproc version 1.4.0?  I'm facing this issue from the day I started this cluster but it was for development only, so I ignored initially.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's possible that this issue was fixed in a new subminor versions after 1.4.0 release, i.e 1.4.22.

Comment: I also tried talking with support team but it doesn't seem to be known issue to them, I thought It might me something with the way dataproc handles the HA.

Comment: Did you try a newer version though?

Comment: No Igor, I just wanted to confirm the issue before spinning up the new cluster from scratch.

Comment: Please, let me know if issue persists in latest 1.4 image version and we will take a look into it if this is the case.

Comment: So I just started one new cluster with dataproc image version 1.4.22-debian9, but again I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Thanks, Igor. It's working now. 
JournalNode had permission issues while writing the node label stats in hdfs.